# Unnest function on temporary Bigquery table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I was wondering if i can use unnest to a temporary table?

I tried the below but i got a warning that hits is not recognized.

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH ALL__TABLES__ AS (
  SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES__`
)
SELECT hits.sourcePropertyInfo AS Property_Info
FROM ALL__TABLES__,
UNNEST (hits) AS hits

LIMIT 10
```

Comment: There is no column named `hits` in the `__TABLES__` meta-table. Where are you seeing otherwise?

Comment: `unnest()` works with any array - regardless where it comes from ...

Comment: @ElliottBrossard yes there is a column called hits inside the dataset.

Comment: No, there is not, unless you meant to query a different table.

Answer (score 0):

Following your ALL__TABLES__ creation, this is what I get as a result:

```
#standardSQL
WITH ALL__TABLES__ AS (
  SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES__`
)
SELECT *
FROM ALL__TABLES__
```

[That will result in this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv5ru.png)

In ALL__TABLES__ you can query the tables metadata: `project_id`, `dataset_id`, `table_id`, `creation_time`, `last_modified_time`, `row_count`, `size_bytes` and `type`, but you cannot query `hits`, even if the column is present in your project dataset.

You can SELECT and UNION ALL the contents of the tables in your dataset [by using the wildcard * instead of **TABLES**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables):

```
WITH ALL__TABLES__ AS (
  SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.*` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.*
)
```

However, when running this in a dataset with different column count, not all data will be considered in ALL__TABLES__, so it might be possible that you don’t find the `hits` column. Be sure that all the tables in your dataset have the same column format so you will be able to find and unnest `hits`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Will try again!